# onload - Время загрузки двух изображений выравнивается, хотя должно быть разным. Почему?

Tags: javascript, html5

В веб интерфейсе на HTML5/JS возможно просматривать веб камеру и/или рабочий стол клиента. Частота кадров разная - для камеры 20 кадров в секунду (50 мс задержка), для десктопа 500 мс - 2 кадра в секунду.
Если транслировать отдельно камеру, всё ОК - имеем 20 кадров, но стоит включить одновременную трансляцию, так частота кадров камеры становится равной частоте кадров десктопа, даже если функции `onload` сделать разными. Вот код для ясности:

```
function RefreshFrame(){
    var Delay = (this.name==='Camera')?50:500;
    var Hold = GetTickCount(); // function GetTickCount(){return new Date().getTime();}
    while(Hold + Delay > GetTickCount()){continue;}
    this.src = TargetURN+'?'+this.name+'='+Data+"&time="+Hold;
}
function SetDevice(Object, Switch){
    if (Switch){
        Object.onload = RefreshFrame;
        Object.onerror = RefreshFrame;
        Object.src = TargetURN+'?'+Object.name+'='+Data+'&time='+GetTickCount();
        Object.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else{
        Object.onload = null;
        Object.onerror = null;
        Object.style.display = 'none';
        Object.src = '';
    }
}
// Вызов
SetDevice(Camera, true);
SetDevice(Screen, true);
```

**Есть какие-то моменты, которые я не учёл, или это просто тормоза браузера?**

*PS: размер кадра с камеры ~ 6 кб, десктопа - ~ 250 кб. Вроде `onload` для элементов должен асинхронно работать...*

Comment: `while(Hold + Delay > GetTickCount()){continue;}`, эм... а речь точно про js?

Comment: в чем смысл этой строчки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в строке

```
while(Hold + Delay > GetTickCount()){continue;}
```

Судя по всему, задумка была *подождать* Delay, и обновить src картинки.

Так как Javascript выполняется в одном потоке, данный цикл вешает весь браузер, до момента, пока не выйдет из цикла, таким образом при значительных значениях Delay это стало бы особо заметно.

Вместо данного цикла нужно использовать [функцию setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), которая как раз и предназначена для того, чтобы выполнить функцию через заданный таймаут.

Функция может принять следующий вид:

```
function RefreshFrame(){
    var Delay = (this.name==='Camera')?50:500;
    var Hold = GetTickCount();
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.src = TargetURN+'?'+this.name+'='+Data+"&time="+Hold;
    }, Delay);
}
```

В данном примере использована [стрелочная функция](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), для того, чтобы `this` внутри обработчика таймера ссылался на ту же картинку, что и внутри функции RefreshFrame

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это то что нужно!